# What could this conduit under my basement slab be?

Tags: basement, conduit, slab

I was moving a shower drain for a basement bathroom and exposed what looks like some kind of cable conduit under the slab. It looks like the kind that's slit all along the length of it and just snaps over something without needing to feed stuff through, it also has small holes every couple of ribs. This is on the opposite side of the house from the electrical panel.

I put a couple holes in it with the jackhammer, not expecting anything to be there, but they aren't big enough to see what's inside. I haven't damaged anything obvious (lights are on, etc), and it's clearly not supposed to be water-tight, but still...
[image]

Comment: That is a drain pipe.  I know it as Big O.  It has holes/slits in it to let in water and drain it away.

Comment: @crip659 Thanks, that makes sense. Do these run around the whole perimeter of the foundation? I guess it's not much of an issue then if I put a couple extra holes in it.

Comment: It will depend on the drainage design, but usually the whole perimeter is a good guess/common design.  Extra holes will let more stuff in that might block it, but that section does not seem to matter that much.  The slit and no sock.